# Navigation Bar a:hover not working (background color not changing)

Tags: css, html, navbar, background-color

I am trying to code a navigation bar, something that should be simple. All good navigation bars have an `a:hover` attached to do something like change the background color. This doesn't work in my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/cn1as7nu/

**UPDATE**:

Problem solved!

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: no problem. I fixed the first few. but you still need to resolve the multiple `id` thing. that will come back to bite you at some point. https://jsfiddle.net/cn1as7nu/1/